# Проблема с Mysql и $_POST

Tags: php, mysql

Как мне ришить проблему с подключеннием к mysql
когда я пишу `$name = $_POST["name"];` то у меня не подключает к mysql, а когда пишу `$name = name;` то у меня вписувуютса данные но у них пустые поля

[image: вот]

и у меня такая форма может в ней ошибка:

```
                <form method="post" action="" style="display: block; width: 90%; margin: 20px; padding: 20px;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Ваше имя:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Ваше имя">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Ваш email:</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Ваш email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Товар:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="product" readonly>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Цена:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" readonly>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Купить</input>
                </form>
```

ну а это подключенние к mysql:

```
<?php
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "shop";

$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$product = $_POST["product"];
$price = $_POST["price"];
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO tovar (name, email, product, price)
VALUES ($name, $email, $product, $price)";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

я думаю что должно быть так но данные не вписувуются в mysql: (а PhpStorm жалуется но не говорит в чом проблемма)

```
$name = name;
$email = email;
$product = product;
$price = price;
```

я в PHP новичок так что не судите строго
и простите за мой русский

Comment: Массив $_POST появляется лишь тогда, когда вы отправляете данные формы, когда срабатывает событие submit, при первоначальной загрузке страницы у вас этого массива нет. Раз action в форме не задано, значит обработка данных происходит здесь же. вы хотя бы проверьте наличие массива перед присваиванием значений из него в переменные.

Comment: как я понял нужно создать например postform.php и в него вписать код каторий я писал для mysql и взять заменить туда
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$product = $_POST['product'];
$price = $_POST['price']; вот так и в <form action="postform.php"><form> и призагрузке сайта должно обробатывать данные и вписовать их в $_POST а потом при нажатие sumbit отправляет данные на mysql. Но у меня ошибка: Error: INSERT INTO tovar (name, email, product, price) VALUES (, , , )

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, как уже вам сообщил @Quazimorda, нужно делать проверку "пришли ли нужные нам данные" (хотя бы какой-то минимальный isset($_POST), но должен быть).

Во-вторых, лучше разделять front и back-end логику, т.е. вынести в отдельный файл, хотя бы, сохранение. Так же, лучше разделять логику, сделать config и туда поместить данные для подключения к бд, само подключение вынести в отдельный файл и т.п...

В-третьих, нельзя сразу с $_POST массива вставлять данные в запрос. Нужно либо их валидировать, либо использовать [подготавливаемые запросы](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Ну, и, касательно вашей проблемы:

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
...
```

Так записано было правильно (но нет обработки данных!!) и нет проверки отправлена была форма или нет, то есть у вас при каждом заходе на страницу будет срабатывать сохранение, даже без отправки формы.

Сам же запрос не выполняется ("криво проходит") потому что вы строковые данные вставляете в запрос как целочисленные. Можно просто добавить кавычки к переменным.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tovar (name, email, product, price)
                   VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$product', '$price')";
```

*p.s. лучше именовать абсолютно всё на английском, а не использовать транслитерацию, читать больно*

Comment: Ну ладно автор не может, но вы то зачем в качестве примера подставляете данные прямо в запрос?! Есть же подготовленные запросы.

Comment: Для этого в ответ добавил кучу текста и в конце просто указал на ошибку